# How can I programatically populate a WPF Grid in C# based on my database rows?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml

I am getting results from a MySQL Database and I want to display them in a two-column grid.  I have set up my grid in my MainWIndow.xaml file and have added the column definitions.  Since the number of rows in the grid depends on the number of database results, I define the grid rows in the c# code.  For some reason, the grid.SetRow and grid.SetColumn methods are throwing the following errors:

```
'System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetRow(System.Windows.UIElement, int)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.
```

I do not know how to fix this because I do not know what 'Qualify it with a type name instead' means.  How do I fix this?

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString());
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM maps ORDER BY MapTitle";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    RowDefinition MapRow = new RowDefinition();
                    int CurrentRow = 0;
                    int CurrentColumn = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        /* Generate the preview attachment image */
                        Attachment PreviewFile = new Attachment();
                        PreviewFile.Details(Convert.ToInt32(reader["PreviewID"]));
                        BitmapImage MapPreview = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgURL() + "/" + PreviewFile.FileName, UriKind.Relative));
                        MapPreview.DecodePixelWidth = 384;
                        MapPreview.DecodePixelHeight = 216;

                        /* Generate the map title header */
                        TextBlock MapHeader = new TextBlock();
                        MapHeader.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["MapTitle"]);
                        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  //convert hex
                        MapHeader.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#243C5E");
                        MapHeader.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#F2F3F5");

                        /*  If we're in the right column, set it to the left column for the next iteration */
                        if(CurrentColumn == 1){
                            CurrentColumn = 0;
                            CurrentRow++;
                        /* Otherwise, update which column we're in. */
                        } else {
                            CurrentColumn++;
                            MapRow = new RowDefinition();
                        }

                        MapGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(MapRow);
                        /* Add the map title header to the grid in the appropriate row and column. */
                        MapGrid.Children.Add(MapHeader);
                        MapGrid.SetRow(MapHeader, CurrentRow);
                        MapGrid.SetColumn(MapHeader, CurrentColumn);
                        /* Add the map preview image to the grid in the appropriate row and column. */
                        MapGrid.Children.Add(MapPreview);
                        MapGrid.SetRow(MapPreview, CurrentRow);
                        MapGrid.SetColumn(MapPreview, CurrentRow);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("A database error occurred while gathering the results.");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
```

Here is my XAML for the grid:

```
<Grid Name="MapGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: use DataGrid or ListView Instead.

Answer (score 0):

@JSJ is absolutely right. You should use GridView or ListView. Grid is for layout not for displaying data. 
I like ListView more, you can use MVVM pattern to bind the rows you've got for the DB to your list view. Or just hard code it: `yourListView.Items = itemsFromDb`